# Digit small numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem

A digit small number is a positive integer \$n\$ such for any two numbers that multiply to \$n\$, their total number of digits is more than the digits in \$n\$.

In otherwords: there are no two positive integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ such that:

\$
ab = n
\$

and

\$
\left\lfloor\log_{10}(a)\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\log_{10}(b)\right\rfloor <\left\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\right\rfloor
\$

For example 363 is digit small.  It can be made as the product of two numbers 3 ways

\$
1\times363=363\\
3\times121=363\\
11\times33=363\\
\$

Each time we have 4 digits on the left hand side and 3 on the right hand side.

As another example 48 is not digit small because we can write it as

\$
6\times8=48
\$

where each side of the equation has 2 digits in total.

## Task

Given a positive number output one of two distinct values depending on whether the input was digit small.  For example you could output `1` when the input is digit small and `0` if it is not, or `True` and `False` etc.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes.

## Test cases

Here are the first 25 digit small numbers:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,17,19,22,23,26,29,31,33,34,37,38,39,41,43
```

## Hint

> If you drop the test cases into OEIS you will get [A122427](http://oeis.org/A122427).  This sequence is useful, but you will have to prove where it is the same, or find the cases in which it is different.

Comment: How big numbers do we have to handle?

Comment: Do the output values have to be consistent?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

```
n->!sumdiv(n,d,Str(d)>Str(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XTrG4NDcls0wjTydFJ7ikSCNF0w5E5Wlq/k/LB9IKtgqGOgqmBjoKBUWZeSVAASUFXTsgkQZSo/kfAA)

Using the hint.

> Let \$\#n\$ denote the number of digits in \$n\$. Then \$n\$ has a divisor \$d\$ that is lexicographically greater than \$n\$ \$\iff\$ \$d * 10^{\#n-\#d} > n\$ \$\iff\$ \$n/d < 10^{\#n-\#d}\$ \$\iff\$ \$\#(n/d) \le \#n - \#d\$ \$\iff\$ \$n\$ is not digit small.

Comment: Nice proof of the hint!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Using the hint, suggested by [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
Ñ§{θQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9i4nNqksv/wxMPLa8@tyPw/38A)

Cast the divisors `Ñ` to string `§`, sort `{`, is the last one `θ` equal to the input `Q`?

Or 9 bytes without the hint, -1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen):

```
ÑÂøεS∍‹}P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDTYd3nNsa/Kij91HDztqA//@NzYwB)

```python
Ñ           # divisors of the input
 Âø         # zip with its reverse
   ε   }    # map over the divisor pairs
    S       #   split into a single list of digits
     ∍      #   extend the input to that length
      ‹     #   is the input less than the extended version?
        P   # product / boolean all
```

Comment: [9 bytes: `ÑÂøεS∍‹}P`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDTYd3nNsa/Kij91HDztqA//@NzYwB) (outputting `1` for digit small numbers, `0` for others)

Comment: [5 bytes using the hint: `Ñ§{θQ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MRDy6vP7Qj8/9/YzBgA) (also outputs `1` for digit small numbers, 0 for others)

Comment: I don't think this is 5 bytes? § and θ aren't in ASCII, certainly, and I don't know of any common character encoding which (1) contains all these characters and (2) contains less than 256 characters total.

Comment: @rationalis 05AB1E has its [own codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) which contains all these characters. Though you're right, this is not a very common encoding ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 31 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(n,k=1:n)any(c("",k[!n%%k])>n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoMwEAXQ72YXCsIMXAqTSdUIdiOlHyE0KEpqH1JcfXrOu6SxpD3H7/zMlLGMMmQO@aBIdY3lVuWmWe58zVwSaatsErmejQnren689rDSb5rjRNUnbNt6kAxOkZhhTpEEFgqHC1p06OEhAlFIB/GwFlZhW1gPFahCHbSD9lAPJ3DKXP4)

Using the hint ([proof in @alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237310/55372)).

Outputs `FALSE` for digit small number and `TRUE` otherwise.

Converts list of divisors `k[!n%%k]` to `character` by prepending empty string. Then compares the vector with `n` (casted implicitly to `character`); `"">n` is always `FALSE`.

---

Without the hint:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 48 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(n,k=1:n,d=k[!n%%k],`-`=nchar)all(-d+-(n/d)>-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRCoJAEAXQ5/YvehBm6FrMzqauYD8SgaItirKZJdHXW@f1LFuotrDG9j08IkWMlZQRXTVe9zFJxhvqtK5i2zcLN9NEaXdIKZ46vqSRt0CaKZtArmBj/n@8P9dmok8/tD29mnmeviSlUwRmmF1LAguFwxkZchTwEIEoJId4WAursBmshwpUoQ6aQwuohxM4Zd5@)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda n:any(`i`>`n`>n%i<1for i in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwFEbhvU9xF6GBDolj0I4@gVsVcsVEL9Q/5SYOffpocXA931nW@szYt3S8tJlftzsTPGPtg4QxIIzYycGlrCQkIGU8Yg9j2pbwT24gZ601viMuJWql9N02n876jgOdeC7x2pEkQv6pX1RQCe0D)

Outputs `True`/`False` negated. Looks for an `i` that's a divisor of `n` and is lexicographically smaller than `n`. The two conditions are combined into an inequality chain, connected by Python 2's willingness to compare strings and numbers (strings are bigger).

This chain also benefits from short-circuiting. Checking `i=0` would trigger an error when we check `n%i`, but since `0` is never lexicographically above `n`, the first condition always fails and the second one is never reached.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>16</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
KḂZƛṅL;?Lc
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K%E1%B8%82Z%C6%9B%E1%B9%85L%3B%3FLc&inputs=28&header=&footer=)

Hmm yes <s>Jelly</s> 05AB1E porting goes brr. Outputs `0` for digit small, `1` for everything else.

### Explained

```
KḂZƛṅL;?Lc
K            # factors_of(input)
 Ḃ           # that, and that reversed 
  Z          # zip those two -> pairs of factors that have product = input
   ƛṅL;      # join each on spaces and take lengths
       ?L    # input length
         c   # is in that list?
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Expects \$n\$ as a string. Works in theory up to \$n=99999999999\$ (although the call stack will overflow way before that).

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>k>n||!n[(k+[n/k]).length-1]&f(n,-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwEAC/kl6aXdQt0l4j9B0iJdhoY@JGYigUpF9P08NchmEW/db7GO2WGg5Pk/OkgGuHqnMdH8eJe3BVzxc3IHnDc3o17XCeStN8HeYx8B68IR9m6InoHqP@wO2KA616A3jUglGoTrCoRFuQEmmyPpkI/PflhEhLsAyyloj5Bw)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>35</s>  33 bytes

Using [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237308/58563)'s method is significantly shorter.

Expects \$n\$ as a string. Returns \$0\$ for *true* or \$1\$ for *false*.

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>k>n?0:[k]>n>n%k|f(n,-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczBCgIhEIDhV7FDOEPuUNQp0Og5liVk03C1cXGXIIhe3ezwX77DP9mXXcYS5rXjfHe1eg2sImoTDV/25z4Ohg1v48c3774R65h5yclRyg/oiehain3D6YgDPe0McFOCUWgjWOzEoSUlkg9pdQX475u2QqQpBwapJGL9AQ)

Comment: This challenge feels like the perfect oppurtunity to use JS's default `sort`.  Oh well, another time.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>12</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
─░s┤l¡Þ
```

Outputs `1` if it's a digit small number, `-1` if not.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIZH0yYWP5qyJMf28Lz//w25jLiMuUy4TLkMDbiMgAgoYMRlZMxlZMJlZMplbGYMAA)

Almost halved the byte-count by using the hint.

**Original 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) answer without using the hint:**

```
─_x^mÆy£l£>╓
```

Outputs `1` if it's a digit small number, `0` if not.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIb4irjcw22VhxbnHFps92jq5P//DbmMuIy5TLhMuQwNuIyACChgxGVkzGVkwmVkymVsZgwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
─           # Get a list of divisors from the (implicit) input-integer
 ░          # Convert each integer to a string
  s         # Sort this list of strings lexographically
   ┤        # Pop the last item (unfortunately without popping the remainder-list)
    l       # Push the input as string
     =      # Check that it's equal to this integer
            # (if not, it implicitly indices since it's a string, resulting in -1)
      Þ     # Discard everything from the stack except the top (to get rid of the
            # remainder-list)
            # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)

─           # Get a list of divisors from the (implicit) input-integer
 _          # Duplicate this list
  x         # Reverse the copy
   ^        # Zip the two lists together, creating pairs
    m       # Map over these strings,
     Æ      # using five characters as inner codeblock:
      y     #  Join the pair together to a string
       £    #  Pop and push its length
        l£  #  Push the length of the input (as string) as well
          > #  Check if the length is larger than the input-length
    ╓       # After the map: pop and push its minimum to check if any were falsey
            # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 40 bytes

```
Input N
max(1,seq(Inot(fPart(N/I)),I,1,N
min(int(log(Ans))+int(log(N/Ans))≥int(log(N
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed. Outputs `1` for digit small numbers and `0` for others.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
ÆDDṀḌ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm4vLw50ND3f02P4/3H6s/f9/ExMA)

-7 bytes (50%!) thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!
-1 byte thanks to ovs!

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//w4ZEROG5ouG5quG4jD3/LMOHxZLhuZgkSylZ//80OCwgMzYz) using the hint. I'm not too skilled with Jelly, so can probably be a byte shorter.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Very nice, I knew the hint had to be useful! I can't spot any obvious golfs at the moment, but I'll take a proper look when not on mobile :)

Comment: `Ṁ` saves a byte over `ṢṪ`: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm4vLw50ND3f02P4/3H6s/f9/ExMA

Comment: @ovs Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 52 bytes

```
.+
*
Lv$`(_+)$(?<=^(\1)+)
$.=,$.1$#2
+`.,.
,
A`\d
^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc07asNAGADhfq7hNUiRWPZ/7AsijCs3OYJxFLCLNCmM8fUVHWC@eT5ev38/sh2Hy7rFiQ@@3mEdvqcxDKfP5TZcZZxGQlzmECUclGmNc2TmvF7v3MK2CYrhZAqVRkcSIogihjiSkYJUpCEdTejeKGqooxktaEUb2rGECbaThjmWsYJVrGEdT7jgiu9HxzNe8Io3vJPTPw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
Lv$`(_+)$(?<=^(\1)+)
```

For each pair of factors of the input...

```
$.=,$.1$#2
```

... convert the input back to decimal and append the two factors.

```
+`.,.
,
```

For each pair of factors, check whether this is a digit small factorisation.

```
A`\d
```

Delete all factorisations that were digit small.

```
^$
```

Check that there are no factorisations left.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>49</s> 40 bytes

Prompts for integer. 1 = true, 0 = false.

```
×/(+/⍴¨⍕¨v,n÷v←↑⌽(0=m|n)/m←⍳⌊n*.5)>⍴⍕n←⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/@Hp@hra@o96txxa8ah36qEVZTp5h7eXAeUftU181LNXw8A2tyZPUz8XJNK7@VFPV56WnqmmHVADUHkeSLRv6n@gSVz/07hMLLjSuIzNjLm4AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¥â ñs Ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=peIg8XMgzA&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwLDExLDEyLDEzLDE0LDE1LDE2LDE3LDE4LDE5LDIwLDIxLDIyLDIzLDI0LDI1LDI2LDI3LDI4LDI5LDMwLDMxLDMyLDMzLDM0LDM1LDM2LDM3LDM4LDM5LDQwLDQxLDQyLDQzLDQ0LDQ1LDQ2LDQ3LDQ4LDQ5XQpbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTEsMTMsMTcsMTksMjIsMjMsMjYsMjksMzEsMzMsMzQsMzcsMzgsMzksNDEsNDNdCi1m)

- port of @Kevin Cruijssen answer.

```
 ¥       - input equal?
      Ì  - last element of
 â       - divisors of input
   ñs    - sorted lexicographically
```

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh, <s>118</s> 94 bytes

```
for i ({1..$1})(($1%i))||a+=($i);for e ($a)for f ($a)[[ $#e+$#f -le $#1 && e*f -eq $1 ]]&&<<<0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY349LyixQyFTSqDfX0VAxrNTU0VAxVMzU1a2oStW01VDI1rUEKUhU0VBI1Qaw0MCs6WkFFOVVbRTlNQTcnFcg2VFBTU0jVAnJTCxVUDBViY9XUbGxsDCC2QC1bEm1iEAtlAwA)

*Thanks to @pxeger for saving 24 bytes!*

My first Zsh answer, uses the obvious solution. Outputs 0s if the number is *not* digit-small, nothing if it is. 99% sure there exists a shorter solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｎθ⬤…·¹θ∨﹪θι‹Ｌθ⁺ＬιＬ÷θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvLCsIwEEX3fkWWU4hg110JbgJVi3@QpkMbGCfm@ftpNXhX93XMpoNxmmpV/Mnpkd8zBvDdcJqC5QRXIlBsKEdb8KV5Reil8J0UzwB3t2Ry4KWwRzFijDAir2mD72E6oH9u@88qTjdb7IKNaxpq7S/1XGgH) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for digit small, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      Input `n` as a number
   …·¹θ                 Inclusive range from `1` to `n`
  ⬤                     All values satisfy
          ι             Current value
        ﹪               Does not divide
         θ              Input `n`
       ∨                Logical Or
             θ          Input value
            Ｌ           Length
           ‹            Is less than
                ι       Current value
               Ｌ        Length
              ⁺         Plus
                   θ    Input `n`
                  ÷     Integer divide
                    ι   Current value
                 Ｌ      Length
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.1, 60 bytes

```
n=...for x=1,n do c=c or n%x<1 and#(x..n/x)<=#n end print(c)
```

Takes a number from command line arguments, prints `false` if the number fits the definition, otherwise prints `true`.

The algorithm simply checks if there is any number `a` up to `n` that is a factor of `n` and whose string concatenation with `b=n/x` is longer than string `n`; if yes, switch the output to `true` (does not fit the definition).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>77</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>74</s></sup> 70 bytes

```c
r;d;s(n){n=log10(n);}f(n){for(r=d=1;++d<n;)r&=n%d||s(d)-~s(n/d)>s(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHRTsIwFH3nK26WYDbowtoOlZTxYvwK4YGsHRKhI@0SFwE/3XmGY1EfjUvb9Jx7zu29u3m8yfOmcUorH9roaLNdueEJrupctERRutBlOuNqPNZzqyJ3k9mhPp18qKP4HaaJjhb@Ymi2tqL9emvDiI4DwtcSlfGVf1pRRkfOSDCSjFJGU0a3jO4Y3TOaMeKIcUQ4GA4sIBTAAiIBLBGXwBJWCY2ETYJPwaetL8GGhyPOkZvDx6ER4EX7LngBXsArWi942RYDTkKbAqfirPqyTX0weWV0X/l/reQPq6srL62vKH9euxFOk78Y91VesKwfxbKePWBPA0bfsQw6N0ZJYdva1mpTw5ao7jonv30zZRFem44mHTHqGUXj8UV9nW0/X2T6mvElvFJ9tAirSP3QGmj7H/tbfnCQFGEw1BQvCOfQLy2aqRg51vfrssysurTnwbn5yIvdeuOb@LWJd/tP)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!*
*Saved 4 bytes thanks to [upkajdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/upkajdt)!!!*

Inputs positive integer \$n\$.
Returns \$1\$ if \$n\$ is a digit small number or \$0\$ otherwise.

Comment: [74 Bytes](https://tio.run/##rZHRboIwFIbvfYoTExeQEm2L20zFm2VPMb0wtDgyLYaSjEzZo4/9KJK5y2WkND3f@f9yDicJt0nSNIXSynnWP9p4l2/5FEdVpy1I88IrYh1zFQR6YZVf3MV2pE8n52k//IRpov1l61U6LlTdZLak/Saznk/HAeFpQWlc6V7WFNORMxKMJKOI0YzRPaMHRo@M5ow4chwZDsIRCwgFYgGRQCyRl4glrBIaCZsEj8Cj1jfFCw9HnuNuDh@HRoCL9rvgAlzAK1ovuGyLAZPQRogjUau@bFMdTFIa3Vf@X2v6h9XVleTWlZS8booxdpO8meJS3nBVPYtVNX/COxsy@hnLYefGOMlrW8usNhVsU9UdF@SyD5On3rVpf9KBcU8UBcFZfZ1tP1/cdJnxOb1WN1mHbOqV/i01oP0P/m07FJCk3nCkKVwS9pFbWTRVMnKs79vFsVl319aDuvlK0t1m65rwvQl3@28 "C (gcc) – Try It Online") by removing ternary operator and removing +1 to log10()

Comment: @AZTECCO Ah, nice stuff - change the `x+2>y+1` to just `x+1>y` and use logical or on the divisibility - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-formulas-in-excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173), 73 bytes

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(A1^0.5),b,FILTER(a,MOD(A1,a)=0),MIN(LEN(b&A1/b))>LEN(A1))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnWgLkA8xc5MQj0N6?e=FNTa3q)

Works for n < 1,099,513,724,929 = (2^20 + 1) ^ 2.  You could get it down to 69 bytes by removing ^0.5; but it would only work for n <= 2^20.

Comment: Generally golfing trumps size constraints. For example, default variable declarations in C are fine: `n` (defaulting to `int x`) is best for golfing even thought it constrains size to \$32\$-bit where `long n` is \$64\$-bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:max(`x`for x in range(1,n+1)if n%x==0)==`n`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq8wmcKhFJrQI5i4aNSXkV6SFnd7eK997Zyy9qzwh7UcgbCk045vXXKlRBNWA6zR2wmg5KmFoIjOLePheasRr1LjVMfcf)

Comment: `<1` instead of `==0` since the modulo can't be negative, and you can remove your `+1` to convert the other `==` to a `<`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).all?{|x|n%x>0||x.to_s<=n.to_s}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PUy8xJ8e@uqaiJk@1ws6gpqZCryQ/vtjGNg9M19b@L1AAKTQ0MNDUK07NSU0uASlOi66Irf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

### With hint

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 10 bytes

```
Jfcqb0>m==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/W9oYFD93ystuTDJwC7X1vZ/rZv/fwA)

```
J      # Duplicate input
fc     # Factors
qb0>m  # Maximum lexicographically
==     # are Equal
```

### Without hint

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 26 bytes

```
PppPfcJ<-z[m{imlnpPln.>}r&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/W9oYFD9P6CgICAt2ctGtyo6tzozNyevICAnT8@utkjtf62b/38A)

```
Pp      # Push input to store
pP      # Retrieve input
fc      # Factors (of input)
J       # Duplicate factors
<-z[    # Zip list of factors with reversed list of factors
m{      # Map (for each pair of factors)
  im    # Concat factors
  ln    # Total number of digits
  pPln  # Digits in input
  .>    # Greater than (that of factors)
}
r&      # For all factors
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>146</s> <s>164</s> 89 bytes

*Had to add 18 bytes because the previous version only supported numbers up to 10000. Now it should support up to numbers around \$10^{10}\$. Thanks [@fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241) for helping me with this change.*

***EDIT**: Turns out, the change mentioned above actually allowed me to essentially halve the number of bytes in my code...*

\$f(n)\$ returns 0 if \$n\$ is a digit small number, 1 if it is not.

```
a=[1...sqrtn]
b=a[mod(n,a)=0]
g(l)=floor(logl)
f(n)=\sign(\total(\{g(b)+g(n/b)<g(n),0\}))
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o9yvnub2rg)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycibiivzht)

Probably not the best way to do it, but for now I think it is good enough. Uses the formula given in the problem.